# p:datatable: How to edit data in a p:dialog?

Tags: primefaces, datatable

**Context**

I have a datatable with a button that opens a dialog when clicked. That dialog shows additional data (xml content) in a p:inputTextarea

**Question**

Now I would like to make this p:inputTextarea editable and have the changes reflected in the object of the datatable. I wanted to add a commandbutton in the dialog to save the changes. How do I get a reference to the selected object ?

**Xhtml**

```
<h:form id="alltxform">
    <p:dataTable id="tablealltx" var="transaction" value="#{transactionListModel.txList}">    
        <p:column>
            <p:commandButton update=":alltxform:xmlDetail" oncomplete="PF('dialog').show()">  
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{transaction}"
                        target="#{transactionListModel.selectedTx}" />  
            </p:commandButton>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>

    <p:dialog header="Detail" widgetVar="dialog">
        <p:outputPanel id="xmlDetail">
            <p:inputTextarea readonly="false" id="xmlviewer"
                    value="#{transactionListModel.selectedTx.xml}" />
        </p:outputPanel>
    </p:dialog> 
</h:form>
```

**Model**

```
package model;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class TransactionListModel implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private List<TransactionVO> txList;
    private TransactionVO selectedTx;

    public TransactionVO getSelectedTx() {
        return selectedTx;
    }

    public void setSelectedTx(TransactionVO selectedTx) {
        this.selectedTx = selectedTx;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        txList = new ArrayList<TransactionVO>();
    }

    public List<TransactionVO> getTxList() {
        return txList;
    }

    public void clearList(){
        txList = new ArrayList<TransactionVO>();
    }
}
```

**Button**

I want to add this button to the dialog.

```
<p:commandButton value="OK" onclick="PF('dialog').hide();" actionListener=""/>
```

I read about cellEdit events, but that's not really what I need. I need a reference to my transaction object inside the dialog in order to save the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the dialog will look like -

```
<p:dialog header="Detail" widgetVar="dialog">
    <p:outputPanel id="xmlDetail">
        <p:inputTextarea readonly="false" id="xmlviewer"
                value="#{transactionListModel.selectedTx.xml}" />
        <p:commandButton value="OK" onclick="PF('dialog').hide();" actionListener=""/>
    </p:outputPanel>
</p:dialog>
```

And the action will refresh the model, before refreshing the table?

And you want to access TransactionListModel.selectedTx?

Well if its in the model and accessible from the controller then just -

```
actionListener="#{yourController.yourAction(transactionListModel.selectedTx)}"
```

And Update the underlying datastructure in the yourAction method, before updating :tablealltx:tablealltx

Comment: Of course. Sometimes it's right in front of me and I don't see it. Thanks

Comment: For some reason, transactionListModel.selectedTx is not set and stays null. How do I set it ? The f:setPropertyActionListener does not seem to work here

Comment: Populate using the first button instead of setPropertyActionListener

Comment: Using the setter of the bean ? I thought one should not call then directly

Comment: I dont think its that bad a way to populate from data table